# download_url() appears as grey icons

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, codex

I try to download pictures from url from different website with the command `download_url($url, $timeout)` to get it in the media library. And after, I make a `wp_handle_sideload($file, $overrides)`.

```
$temp_file = download_url( $url, 5 );
$file = array(
     'name'     => basename($url),
     'type'     => 'image/jpg',
     'tmp_name' => $temp_file,
     'error'    => 0,
     'size'     => filesize($temp_file),
);
$overrides = array(
     'test_form' => false,
     'test_size' => true,
);
// Move the temporary file into the uploads directory
$results = wp_handle_sideload( $file, $overrides );
```

The file downloads correctly, but appears as a grey icon in the library. But if I open the file with the link, the picture is ok.

[image: grey icons]

Is it the correct method to download pictures ?
After the download will be ok, I want to associate the media as thumbnail to a post. I think with the `wp_insert_attachment()` and `set_post_thumbnail()` functions.

Thanks

Comment: Do you create the media Meta data?

Comment: I didn't do anything else than I wrote. How do you do you create metadata ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `wp_handle_sideload` function then, as @xvilo pointed out in a comment, it isn't creating the meta data wordpress needs to display the image in the media library. As I can not see where the `wp_handle_sideload` function is writing the data to the db, I don't understand why the files are being displayed in your media library. So with your approach you are missing a call to `wp_insert_attachment` (as you said yourself) and `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`.

```
$temp_file = download_url( $url, 5 );
$file = array(
     'name'     => basename($url),
     'type'     => 'image/jpg',
     'tmp_name' => $temp_file,
     'error'    => 0,
     'size'     => filesize($temp_file),
);
$overrides = array(
     'test_form' => false,
     'test_size' => true,
);
// Move the temporary file into the uploads directory
$results = wp_handle_sideload( $file, $overrides );

// Write attachment to db
$attachment = [
    'post_title' => basename($results['file']),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => $results['type'],
];
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $results['file'] )

// Generate the attachment's meta data
wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $results['file'] );
```

Or you can just use the [media_handle_sideload](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/) function, as this function is doing that already for you.

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, 0 );
```

After that you can use

```
set_post_thumbnail( $post, $attachment_id );
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's ok with the two lines of your second proposition. Perfect

Comment: Great answer, did not Have the time to write it at the moment

Comment: Rogue, great to see you! In the `set_post_thumbnail( $post, $attachment_id );`, can you explain what the `$post` is?

Comment: @Jonathan Guerin $post is the WP_Post or post_id that DSX wants to associate with the downloaded attachment. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail/